# Provincial Base Mapping Data Sources in Canada

Tags: data, canada

I'm very familiar with the Ontario Base Mapping Data, and am looking for similar data for other Canadian Provinces. Perhaps we can start a list of resources here? I'm looking for something at a larger scale than the standard NTS data.

Ontario Base Mapping - 1:10,000/1:20,000 (depending on latitude) - available from Land Information Ontario (via an [Unrestricted Use Licence](http://www.mnr.gov.on.ca/en/Business/LIO/2ColumnSubPage/272487.html)) or from [GeographyNetwork.ca](http://www.geographynetwork.ca/website/obm/viewer.htm)

Comment: I've done some GIS work for in Alberta and Manitoba as well as the Yukon and at least for these 3 there is no equivalent. Not even remotely close to the level of detail of the data you can get from the LIO warehouse in Ontario. For 50K mapping GeoGratis. As for DEM it's probably best to USGS.

Comment: Agreed Jakub.  In Alberta, you have to purchase the data. It's been privatized, and you get an area approximately the size of 2 1/2 townships for $100.00 (all layers). Or, you're restricted to very coarse GeoGratis data as you said.  Same with the Far North ... not the greatest of data (if there are any even available).  I'll post anything I have in favorites to an answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Canada wide:

- [GeoGratis](http://geogratis.cgdi.gc.ca/geogratis/en/index.html)
- [GeoBase](http://www.geobase.ca/)
- [GeoConnections](http://www.geoconnections.org/)
- [Atlas of Canada](http://atlas.nrcan.gc.ca/site/english/index.html)
- [Open Data Pilot Project](http://www.data.gc.ca/)
- [Open Database of Addresses](https://www.statcan.gc.ca/en/lode/databases/oda) (Statistics Canada)

Provincial:

- [Manitoba Land Initiative](https://mli2.gov.mb.ca)
- [Service New Brunswick](http://www.snb.ca/gdam-igec/e/2900e_1.asp)
- [Information Services Corporation (Saskatchewan)](http://www.isc.ca/MapsandPhotos/GISData/Pages/default.aspx)
- [GeoNova (Nova Scotia)](http://gov.ns.ca/geonova/home/)
- [Alberta Geological Survey](http://www.ags.gov.ab.ca/gis/gis_and_mapping.html)
- [AltaLIS (Alberta)](http://www.altalis.com)
- [GeoBC (British Columbia)](http://geobc.gov.bc.ca/)

Edit: Updated links

Answer (score 3):

For British Columbia we get 98% of our data from

http://www.icisociety.ca/web-map/public-web-map.htm

This data is very current data - see

http://www.icisociety.ca/web-map/upload-history.htm

[Members get access to more datasets]

Other posts mention the other sources we use.

Though do not forget- [Open Street Map](http://www.openstreetmap.org/?lat=52.1368&lon=-106.6482&zoom=14&layers=M) has very good quality data for Canadian Cities (rural areas less so.) - Based on GeoBase and GeoGratis data.

Answer (score 2):

- [GeoBase](http://geobase.ca)
- [GeoGratis](http://geogratis.ca)
- [Atlats of Canada](http://atlas.nrcan.gc.ca/site/english/dataservices/index.html)
- [Stats Canada](http://www.statcan.gc.ca/mgeo/index2-eng.htm) Some of their data is free and the whole site is free when using e-stat or an education account if I recall correctly

In New Brunswick we have [SNB](http://www.snb.ca/gdam-igec/e/2900e_1c_i.asp)

If you have a university account you can tap into IDLS, uWaterloo and uToronto GIS Labs

Answer (score 1):

BC released over 2400 "datasets" with several in GIS format at [www.data.gov.bc.ca](http://www.data.gov.bc.ca)

There is also the [Land and Resource Data Warehouse](http://www.lrdw.ca) that has ported a lot of it's data into data.gov.bc.ca (log in as a guest if you don't care to register a [BCeID](http://www.lrdw.ca/bceid.html))

The TRIM I & II (Terrain Resource Inventory Management) database, though not free is being fragmented where subsets can be found in other 'open data' products such as hydrology now in the Fresh Water Atlas (FWA) and I've even seen contours in CanVec in remote areas of Northern BC.

Answer (score 1):

I have some of the one's already posted on here in my favorites.  I'll try adding a few and hopefully I can fill in some holes that were missed.  Sorry if I post anything that's already been covered:

[ESRI Geography Network](http://www.geographynetwork.ca/) - Not the greatest

[Canadian GIS](http://canadiangis.com/www/data-software)

[Alberta Data - good quality but not free](http://www.altalis.com/)

[Northwest Territories - Mostly just urban areas & not great](http://gis.maca.gov.nt.ca/Website/index.asp)

[VDS Technologies - Global data - Canada covered - pretty decent](http://www.vdstech.com/map_data.htm)

[Saskatchewan Data](https://www.geosask.ca/Portal/)

Lastly, there's a cluster of links posted on the [Laurentian University site](http://www.laurentian.ca/Laurentian/Home/Departments/Library/Finding_information/Data+Stats+GIS/GIS+Free+Data+and+Static+Maps.htm?Laurentian_Lang=en-CA) that some of you may find to be of use