# Land Cover vector data for Saskatchewan / Manitoba Canada

Tags: data, land-cover, canada

Looking for Land Cover (aka Land Use) vector data for Saskatchewan / Manitoba Canada.
Using [Saskatchewan's site](http://gisweb1.serm.gov.sk.ca/imf/imf.jsp?config=http://gisweb1.serm.gov.sk.ca/imf/sk/sites/saskmap/saskmap.xml) I can see the data but not download it as seen [here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kk8LC.png)
Another source is [Data Basin](http://app.databasin.org/app/pages/liveMapPage.jsp?svc=f0cdd92d7f5145d19467d8e999ab1b01) but they also seem to only have it in viewer format.

Comment: Check out http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/12805/1872

Comment: thanks for the previous related thread, there are a few sites there I have not tried yet.

Answer (score 0):

http://mli2.gov.mb.ca/ may have what you are looking for. Also https://data.winnipeg.ca/ - It is Winnipeg specific, but might help too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a raster you're looking for (not a vector), the CEC's land cover data may work http://www.cec.org/tools-and-resources/map-files/land-cover-2005